# How to use mobx observer without the class in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I am using `axios` and `mobx` in my react native project. One of the component (`Home`) on mount calls for a method (`getBirds()`) from a different file where all the API methods are organized.

store.js:

```
class BirdStore {
    @observable birdList = [];

    @action setBirdList = (birds) => {
        this.birdList = birds;
    };
}
```

Home.js:

```
@observer @inject("BirdStore")
export default class Home extends React.Component {    
    componentDidMount() {
        api.getBirds()
        ...
    }
}
```

api.js:

```
@inject('BirdStore') @observer
const api = {    
    getBirds() {
        const url = website + '/api/birds/';
        return axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => {
                this.props.BirdStore.setBirdList(response.data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    },
};
```

But this gives me an error:

> Leading decorator must be attached to a class declaration

I can use the data from the server returned by the `getBirds()` into `Home` component, and then call the `setBirdList()` action, but I wanted to keep api related stuff separately. Is there anyway to use `mobx` without the class so that I can handle all the api related stuff other than the class component itself?

Comment: `@inject('BirdStore') @observer` should only be used on React components, not regular objects like your `api`. Also try to change the order of the decorators on `Home`. `@inject("BirdStore") @observer`

Comment: @Tholle Ok. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is pretty cryptic. They say "must be attached to..." In light of this I would say, yes. You need to attach the decorator to a class. More importantly though, you won't have access to `this.props` otherwise.

Comment: Ah! Yes, the `this.props`. Any ways I hope there was a way.

Comment: Why not define your ```getBirds()``` api call as an @action in your store? That's how i would do it

Comment: Yes. I think that is much better. But then, how can I pass the error from the `catch()` to the Home component. Or should I make another observable variable to hold errors? Any idea?

Comment: yeah you could put your error state in the store. that makes sense to me. create a nice reusable error handler

Comment: Good to know. Anyways could you edit and write your pieces of advice from the comments in the answer, so that I could accept it. Thank you.

Comment: surely. give me a few

Comment: Do you have a repo or codepen that i can look at / edit? Maybe a codesandbox.io?